# Scattering in Black Holes

Tags: black-holes, scattering

Let's take your favorite Black Hole and consider the scattering problem for a scalar field around it. Suppose that the Klein-Gordon equation can be separated in the radial and the angular part. Which are the boundary conditions that we should impose for both equations in order to find the separation constant (in the angular ODE) and the greybody factor from the radial one.